# ArpON not working

Tags: arp-spoofing, ubuntu, dhcp

i'm trying to setup ArpON on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. I have a DHCP network so in the configuration i uncommented the DARPI line, then set RUN to yes.

Then i started the daemon with sudo service arpon start, if i look at `/var/log/arpon/arpon.log`, everything seems to work correctly (however i had to manually add `-i wlan0` to the configuration file.

So i tested it by running `tuxcut` on another computer against it. I expected to see `Reply << Delete entry` on the "victim" pc, but i didn't, in fact the connection has been cut.

Any help?

Comment: try the new version recently released (3.0-ng)